# Unexpected behaviour of System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog() when no other windows are open. Any idea why?

Tags: wpf, dialog, window, modal-dialog, showdialog

I picked up on this (with some effort) when my WPF MVVM application tried to show two consecutive error dialog windows before the main window was launched: After OKing the first window, the application went into a loop and the second error dialog never showed up.

I fixed the problem, but I was hoping someone could enlighten me as to why this happened.

It seems that, if there are no non-modal open windows, if one dialog window has been closed, all new dialog windows are immediately closed, without displaying.

Its very easy to reproduce, so here is some highly conceited code to illustrate the problem. This code is complete, so using just this, you should be able to reproduce it.

Create a Window control for the dialog window, with no code behind, and just the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ForumExampleShowDialogIssue.OKDialogWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="OKDialogWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="This is a Window with a single button. The button is set to Cancel, so it closes the window."
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Margin="5"/>
    <Button Content="OK" IsCancel="True" IsDefault="True"
            Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Next, use the standard WPF `App` class, with nothing new in the XAML, but with the following in the code behind:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    OKDialogWindow alwaysOpen = new OKDialogWindow();
    alwaysOpen.Show();

    while (true)
    {                
        OKDialogWindow dialogWindow = new OKDialogWindow();
        Console.WriteLine("Before show");
        dialogWindow.ShowDialog();
        Console.WriteLine("After show");
    }
}
```

Delete the MainWindow.XAML if it exists, and remove the reference to it from the App.XAML header.

Run. (the program, not like Forest).

**This works as expected.** The `alwaysOpen` window remains open, while one after the other `dialogWindow` instances appear in dialog mode, closing when `OK` is clicked, then showing the next one.

**HOWEVER, this breaks when you change `OnStartup` to the following:**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    while (true)
    {                
        OKDialogWindow dialogWindow = new OKDialogWindow();
        Console.WriteLine("Before show");
        dialogWindow.ShowDialog();
        Console.WriteLine("After show");
    }

}
```

When there is no constantly open window, the first dialog window is the only one that works. After that, countless "Before show" and "After show" messages are printed to the console, but no new dialog windows appear - **they are closed automatically as soon as they are shown.**

**Surely this can't be the intended behaviour? Do you get the same result? Any idea why this happens?**

Comment: Does your App class's default constructor `public App() { }` have `this.InitializeComponent();` call? Because its timely initialization is very essential for sequential ShowDialog() calls to work... I guess in your first ShowDialog automatically becomes the main Window within the Application context and subsequent ShowDialog calls dont work as the assumed "MainWindow" is closed by then....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

- by Default the first open window is the MainWindow.
- By default the only window in the list becomes the MainWindow (if others are to be removed).
- Application Class is designed to exit if no windows are present in
  windows list.

Check this:
http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-wpf-application-class-overview-and-gotcha/

Comment: Thanks, that is an excellent link. I guess I'm the "naive developer" he refers to, because that is exactly what I did.

Comment: I recalled to have read similar code, a few days back. Anyways, glad the link helped.

Answer (score 1):

#### Resolve

You can goto the `App.xaml` file and add this in the root `<Application>` node:

```
ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
```

This means that even when you close all the windows, the application still runs until you explicitly call the `InvokeShutdown()` Method.
The default value of `ShutdownMode` is `OnMainWindowClose`。

#### Explanation

In your first snippet, you create a window first that never close. This is the `MainWindow` and it never close. Thus `Application` never shutdown. But in your second snippet, your `MainWindow` is the first dialog that you have created. Application will shutdown as soon as the window close. Your other dialogs would never show after `Application` shutted down, right?

See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx.