# Show several windows in Startup-Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application with 2 Windows. I removed the `StartupUri` in the App.xaml. Instead I subscribed for the `Startup`-Event to show my Windows.

My two windows are called `Login` and `MainWindow`.

In the `Startup`-Event I have the following code:

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var login = new Login();
    var dialogResult = login.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

When I start my application the Login-Window appears. On the Login-Window there's just one `Button`. On a click on this `Button` the following code will be executed:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult = true;
   Close();
}
```

My expectations are now, that on a click on the `Button` in the Login-Window the MainWindow appears. Instead the complete application is terminated.

If I set a BreakPoint in the StartUp-Event at `if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)` I can enter the brackets and the code in the brackets is executing, but the MainWindow does not appear.

Any ideas why this happens?

I can solve this problem by calling the MainWindow in the Click-Event of the Login-Window like.

```
var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.Show();
Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post might](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6945885/340045) be of interest.  It points to [this reference](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-wpf-application-class-overview-and-gotcha/) which I think describes a similar issue to what you are describing.

Basically the first window that is opened is considered the main window of the application.

I would suggest that you should leave your `MainWindow` as the default and open your login window in the `Loaded` event of the `MainWindow` - if the login is unsuccessful then close the main window (before it gets a chance to open).

Answer (score 1):

It´s because the ShutDown-Property of your application is usually set to "OnLastWindowClose".

So, you have to instantiate your MainWindow before your Login-Window is closed or change the Shutdown-Property.